# Como manter um input radio selecionado em uma view no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Como faria para manter um *input radio* selecionado na minha *view*, tenho os seguintes códigos:

**View:**

```
 <div class="col-md-3"> 
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Tipo de Conta</label>
          <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="CC"> Conta Corrente
          <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="CP"> Conta Poupança
      </div>
  </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function edit($id_conta_bancaria) {
$bancos = Banco::orderBy('nome')->get();
$conta = ContaBancaria::find($id_conta_bancaria);
return view('conta_bancaria.edit')->with(['conta' => $conta, 'bancos' => $bancos]);
}
```

**Model:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ContaBancaria extends Model
{

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
protected $table = 'conta_bancaria';
protected $primaryKey = 'id_conta_bancaria';
protected $fillable = ['id_banco', 'agencia', 'conta', 'tipo', 'operacao'];
```

}

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A solução geral foi a seguinte.

View:

```
<div class="col-md-3"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tipo de Conta</label>
        <p><input type="radio" name="tipo" value="CC" {{ $conta->tipo == 'CC' ? 'checked' : '' }}> Conta Corrente</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="tipo" value="CP" {{ $conta->tipo == 'CP' ? 'checked' : '' }}> Conta Poupança</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 public function edit($id_conta_bancaria) {
    $bancos = Banco::orderBy('nome')->get();
    $conta = ContaBancaria::find($id_conta_bancaria);
    return view('conta_bancaria.edit')->with(['conta' => $conta, 'bancos' => $bancos]);
}
```

Model:

```
class ContaBancaria extends Model
{
protected $table = 'conta_bancaria';
protected $primaryKey = 'id_conta_bancaria';
protected $fillable = ['id_banco', 'agencia', 'conta', 'tipo', 'operacao'];
```

}

Comment: Desculpe, mas isso é só parte da solução, de onde vem a variável `$conta`? Da maneira que a resposta esta agora só ajuda se conhecer o teu código. Claro que é algo simples, mas pra muitos que estão começando no Laravel o conceito de passar as variaveis do controller para o view não é intuitivo, recomendo que edite a resposta.

Comment: Você tem razão, desculpe-me pela falha, fiz edições na resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Para que o [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) possa resgatar o `tipo` escolhido utilize a *`classe`* [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests) (namespace [`Illuminate\Http\Request`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests)), como o código a seguir:

```
public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{

    if ($request->has('tipo'))
    {

        $tipo = $request->input('tipo');

    }

}
```

***EDIÇÃO:*** *o usuário não relatou o problema corretamente, ele queria criar a sua view mediante ao seu model ou conjunto de informações selecionando o tipo que está gravado em sua base de dados.*

***Controller***

```
public function edit($id)
{
    if (isset($id) && is_numeric($id)) 
    {        
        $data['conta'] = $model->find($id);
        return view('editor', $data);
    }
}
```

***View***

```
<div class="col-md-3"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tipo de Conta</label>
        <p><input type="radio" name="tipo" value="CC" {{ $conta->tipo == 'CC' ? 'checked' : '' }}> Conta Corrente</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="tipo" value="CP" {{ $conta->tipo == 'CP' ? 'checked' : '' }}> Conta Poupança</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Desculpe João acho que não elaborei bem a minha pergunta, o que quero mesmo é retornar com o campo marcado quando editar o "Tipo de Conta"

Comment: @geekcom você sempre tem que ser bem específico na sua pergunta, para evitar situações como essa. Por favor, assim que puder, edite sua pergunta adicionando detalhes, mas tome apenas cuidado para não invalidar as respostas já dadas.

Comment: @geekcom fiz a edição para que a minha resposta fique correta, independente de qualquer coisa, coloque as próximas pergunta sempre de maneira ampla, porque, a sua pergunta dá a entender o recebimento e não a criação.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo o uso do [LaravelCollection/html](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html) para gerar seus formúlarios, problemas iguais a este podem ser facilmente resolvidos com a técnica [Form Model Binding](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#form-model-binding). Como este pacote não é mais uma dependência oficial do laravel, você deve instala-lo via composer.

Além de deixar seu código mais legivel, os valores são automaticamente atribuidos a seus devidos campos de acordo com os atributos do "modelo" ligado ao formulário, por exemplo. Isso também funciona automaticamente com os valores que foram explicitamente atribuidos a sessão, eliminando a necessidade do uso de `Input::old('field')`. Veja um simples exemplo:

```
{!! Form::model(new App\User(), ['action' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister']) !!}

    ...

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('email', 'E-mail', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                {!! Form::radio('gender', 0, $user->gender == 0) !!}
                Homem
            </label>
            <label>
                {!! Form::radio('gender', 1, $user->gender == 1) !!}
                Mulher
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    ...

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Dessa forma, o campo para o token CSRF é automaticamente adicionado, e você pode atribuir o método da mesma forma que eu atribui a classe ao formulário.

```
{!! Form::model(new App\User(), ['action' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
```

Comment: Essa seria uma abordagem diferente para resolver o mesmo problema, boa dica.